# Test Case 2 failure in Java Substring Comparisons on HackerRank

Tags: java, string, algorithm, substring, comparison

It's passing all cases except for Test Case 2 and 4. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static String getSmallestAndLargest(String s, int k) {
        String smallest = "";
        String largest = "";
        
        // Complete the function
        // 'smallest' must be the lexicographically smallest substring of length 'k'
        // 'largest' must be the lexicographically largest substring of length 'k'
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int len = s.length() - k;
        for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
            String output = s.substring(i, k++);
            int ascii_code_1 = output.charAt(0);
            int ascii_code_2 = output.charAt(0);
            if (ascii_code_1 < min) {
                min = ascii_code_1;
                smallest = output;
            }
            if (ascii_code_2 > max) {
                max = ascii_code_2;
                largest = output;
            }
        }
        
        return smallest + "\n" + largest;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.next();
        int k = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
      
        System.out.println(getSmallestAndLargest(s, k));
    }
}
```

Here is the Test Case 2:

```
ASDFHDSFHsdlfhsdlfLDFHSDLFHsdlfhsdlhkfsdlfLHDFLSDKFHsdfhsdlkfhsdlfhsLFDLSFHSDLFHsdkfhsdkfhsdkfhsdfhsdfjeaDFHSDLFHDFlajfsdlfhsdlfhDSLFHSDLFHdlfhs
30
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Run your code on "acab", 2. The smallest string will be given as "ac", which is obviously wrong. Step through your code with the debugger to understand why.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that in the for loop you create the substring and compare only the first char, so for instance in an iteration you could have largest = "ffooo" and output = "foooo" but in this case the program skips the conditions and fails (keeping the wrong largest substring).
You must consider this case.